# D3.JS Access to a TSV column with a rather long name

Tags: javascript, d3.js, csv

I am requesting a TSV from a remote server to create a chart in d3.js. I am getting as a result an array of objects with only one property. The property name is quite unconventional and I would like to rename the property OR to access the property with an index number.

```
query ="http://service.iris.edu/irisws/timeseries/1/querynet=IU&sta=ANMO&cha=BHZ&start=2015-07-30T10:21:03&end=2015-07-30T14:21:03&output=ascii2&loc=00"
d3.tsv(query, function(data){
          console.log(data);
      });
```

In the console, I can see a list of object that have the following format:

```
TIMESERIES IU_ANMO_00_BHZ_M, 130732 samples, 20 sps, 2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539, TSPAIR, INTEGER, COUNTS: "2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539 -515308"
TIMESERIES IU_ANMO_00_BHZ_M, 130732 samples, 20 sps, 2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539, TSPAIR, INTEGER, COUNTS: "2015-07-30T12:32:06.469539 -515308"
TIMESERIES IU_ANMO_00_BHZ_M, 130732 samples, 20 sps, 2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539, TSPAIR, INTEGER, COUNTS: "2015-07-30T12:32:06.519539 -515282"
```

With the property name:

```
TIMESERIES IU_ANMO_00_BHZ_M, 130732 samples, 20 sps, 2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539, TSPAIR, INTEGER, COUNTS
```

And values like:

```
"2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539 -515308"
"2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539 -515308"
"2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539 -515308"
```

I know that I can access the values using something like:

```
data[i]["TIMESERIES IU_ANMO_00_BHZ_M, 130732 samples, 20 sps, 2015-07-30T12:32:06.419539, TSPAIR, INTEGER, COUNTS"]
```

But, I do not know in advance (on the client side) some of the information contained in the name of the property.

Any ideas on how to access/rename a property with such unconventional name?

Comment: did any answer help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any object keys with the [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method. In your case:

```
data.forEach(function (d) {
    // Do whatever with the keys
    keys = Object.keys(d);
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
      console.log('key => value', key, d[key]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to change the key of your object to an index and access it by index.

```
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                console.log(data[i]);

                var old_key = Object.keys(data[i]);
                console.log(old_key);

                Object.defineProperty(data[i], i,
                        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(data[i], old_key));
                    delete data[i][old_key];

                console.log(data[i][i]);
                console.log(data[i]);
            };
```